# Chartjs - How to get last 7 days on x-axis labels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, chart.js, linechart

I am trying to get the last seven days on the x-axis of my line-chart (using chartjs). What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instantiate a chart for the last seven days with the following code:

```js
let start = new Date(),
  end = new Date();

start.setDate(start.getDate() - 7); // set to 'now' minus 7 days.
start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // set to midnight.

new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "line",
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        time: {
          min: start,
          max: end,
          unit: "day"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

The date arithmetic works because of the [Date object auto correcting itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#Description) when the value is invalid for the set month.

You'll need to provide your values as `x` (or `t`) & `y` properties, [as specified in the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#input-data).

Comment: Thanks @timclutton, the dates are now showing up as expected. I am not to clear on how the x or t values work. I am looking to also plug in data from a database where the dates match, to the dates on the line chart. I have the data already being pulled in via a working AJAX call; but how could I code to only pulling data relevant to the 'said' date?

Comment: @KOF That's a whole other question related to your design. But write your server-side code to generate the data you need. Either have a URL that provides only the data for the chart, or accept an input param to filter the data, e.g. `?days=7` or `?start=20190101&end=20190107`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put them on the axis yourself. See [this](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html).
Of course, you need to get the information on the y-axis from your backend. How you do this depends on how your data is structured

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with:

```
const dataArray = yourChart.data.datasets[0].data
console.log(dataArray.slice(Math.max(dataArray.length - 7, 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But all I get are values of '0's when I console.log

Comment: i have done it like this and it works, can you provide me your chart.js javascript code?

Comment: I haven't put into my chart.js code yet. I just copied and pasted the above into my code and the console.log comes out as [0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: did you renamed "yourChart" to your chart? as i tested it i console logged me the array with the last 7 items in the data field, and thats the x axis

Comment: yep I did rename it.  How strange.... Can you share with me the entire code, including the code from 'yourChart'?

Comment: here is my example, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/tv82dzj3/3/

Comment: I think there is some confusion on what is being asked. I was looking to get the last 7 dates labelled across the x-axis. Not get the last 7 data points.

Comment: There would be less confusion if you would post some code and describe how your data looks like.