# How to get last 7 days in Line chart(chart JS) with svelte?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, svelte

I want to make a Line chart using chart JS with svelte JS.
In this chart I want to show last 7 days in x-axis and count number in y-axis.

I installed 5 modules to show days label.

But I faced this error when using x-axis "time"

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided.

After installing chartjs-adapter-moment and moment, not fixed.
What should i do to fix this error?

Thank you for every answer

```
"chart.js": "^3.9.1",
"svelte-chartjs": "^3.0.1"
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.1.0",
"chartjs-adapter-moment": "^1.0.0",
```

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte"
  import Chart from "chart.js/auto/auto.js"
  import moment from "moment"
  import "chartjs-adapter-moment"
 



  export let type = "line"

  let chart, options, config


  let start = new Date(),
        end = new Date()

  start.setDate(start.getDate() - 7)
  start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)


  options = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time'
        time: {
          min: start,
          max: end,
          unit: "day"
        }
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }

  config = {
    type: type,
    options: options
  }

  onMount(() => {
      const ctx = chart.getContext("2d")
      let myChart = new Chart(ctx, config)
  })

</script>


<canvas bind:this="{chart}"></canvas>
```

Comment: Could you check the sequence of importing date packages? The sequence is: CHART.JS, moment and the CHART.JS moment adapter

Comment: @user2057925 I changed sequence.. but its not still working

Comment: Ok, having a look more in deep, min and max are options of the scale and not of time node. Move those options to upper level

Comment: Does it work moving min/max??

Comment: @user2057925 both of them is not work... i think the problem is type:"time". when i add this attr error is occurred

Comment: Do you have a reproducable sample since this should work fine, date adapter is installed and imported, options don't affect the error that no date adapter is installed

Comment: In the svelte-chartjs README, that it seems you are using, there is a section where they are talking about the registration of needed items. https://github.com/SauravKanchan/svelte-chartjs#tree-shaking I don't see in your code the registration of TimeScale. Maybe a sample could help to reproduce the issue

Comment: @LeeLenalee This is the sample I referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266605/chartjs-how-to-get-last-7-days-on-x-axis-labels 
But there is a big difference between the chart and the sample I used.
I tried remove and install several times date adapter but still same error

Comment: @user2057925 
I'll work it out the way you said. Thank you very much for answering